# How do you rotate positions from ENU-frame to body frame?

Tags: imu, navigation, rotation, frame

If positions are in the local frame of ENU (or ECEF - either works), how do you rotate that to the body frame of the device?

Logically, I thought that I could use the pitch, roll, and yaw angles of the body frame to form a rotation matrix to apply to ENU positions. However, when I apply the rotation matrix, the positions seems to grow cumulatively as shown in the figure. The across track variations grow over time with each sinusoid wave
[image]

I would like to be able to rotate the positions rather than the velocities in this instance because the positions are obtained from a mechanization process and filtered.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that I could use the pitch, roll, and yaw angles of the body frame

Whether this is true or not depends on the relationship between the Sensor and Body frames. You need to determine Tb2s (the full pose of the Sensor frame relative to the Body frame.) Then the calculation to transform a Ps (position in Sensor frame) to a Pb (position in the Body frame) is:

Pb = Tb2s * Ps

In the case where the Sensor is attached to the Body, it is not necessary to know what the roll-pitch-yaw of the Body frame is. However, if the Sensor is not attached to the Body (maybe it's mounted on a wall), then you'll need to first calculate Tb2s through a frame common to both e.g. Body -> Map -> Sensor.